# a-z post query using AJAX in Wordpress

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

I'm looking to create a navigation for posts that queries all posts and returns those starting with a certain letter. I'd like this to be AJAX-based, so as to avoid reloading the page.

The navigation would be a simple < ul > and look like:

[ # ] [ A ] [ B ] [ C ] ... [ Z ]

As one clicks on each < li >, all posts would be queried, and those whose post_title starts with the < li > 's letter would be returned.

How could a system like this be implemented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Use `range('A', 'Z')` to make the list
- Run a MySQL query where `SUBSTRING(1, 1) == {escapedChar}`

Comment: How would I run the MySQL query AJAX-wise?
I'm supposing I would need to turn each < li > into a button and have it run an AJAX request to run the query onclick.

Comment: @Ian You will learn more doing it anyway, good luck and have fun :)