# Using Substring in MySQL criteria

Tags: mysql, substring

I'm trying to fetch all instances where the 1st letter of a person's first name is equal to *P*.

This is what I came up with, which doesn't return anything:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM people WHERE SUBSTRING(FirstName,0,1) = 'P'";
```

Suggestions?

Comment: Weird, I'd have thought that would work.

Comment: Substring indexes are 1-origin

Comment: @Alex Same here. I'm not entirely sure why it doesn't. The LIKE method works though, but from what I've read, it might be less efficient than using SUBSTRING.

Comment: @Jim Thanks, I've since fixed my [previous answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5347111/a-z-post-query-using-ajax-in-wordpress/5347158#5347158) :)

Answer (score 48, accepted):

The reason your expression doesn't work is that substring() positions are 1-based

Try either of these:

```
where FirstName like 'P%'
```

or

```
where substring(FirstName,1,1) = 'P'
```

Comment: Sweet. I was afraid that would return all instances of the character p, and not just when it's the first character.

Comment: @Ian that would be `like '%P%'`

Comment: @alex 1-origin was more common in the past.  0-origin became the norm with pointer-based arithmetic when it made sense to express indexes as _offsets_ from a base address.  When SQL was originally designed ('70s-'80s) 1-origin and 0-origin were equally prevalent.

Comment: "substring() positions are 1-based" that sentence saved me a ton. Thanks!