# How to remove double quote character in MySQL

Tags: mysql, substring

I've been used [the solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5348153/using-substring-in-mysql-criteria), but it cannot solved for special character.
I've tried

```
SELECT address FROM myDatabase.users
where substring(address,1,1) = '"';
```

What should I do to remove or change any special character or specific character in database like that??

---

anyway, after I ask my friend, he show me that the error come from setting in mysql workbench, I should to unselect "Safe Updates" check box in Edit >> Preferences >> SQL Editor >> Query Editor. thanks for the answer.

Comment: You know that query returns `address` where the first character is a `"` and doesn't do any replacement, right? (just making sure you know this)

Comment: yep, but I just want to remove  double qoute from my field.

Comment: I used it to show first, but it won't show, then replace with it just won't work too..

Comment: Do you want to remove `"`'s everywhere in the string, regardless of what it starts with? If so, your query is a bit misleading.

Comment: yes, but at first character is necessary..

Comment: Does your query return anything?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL - Replace Character in Columns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7734077/mysql-replace-character-in-columns)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you could use the [`REPLACE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace) function, so something like:

```
UPDATE myDatabase.users
SET address = REPLACE( address, '"', '' )
WHERE address LIKE '"%';
```